# Replace promise items with fulfilled value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, promise, es6-promise

The following is the code sample I'll be using for reference.

```
var promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arrayCars.length; i++) {
  promises.push(downloadSpecs({ // function downloadSpecs returns a promise which later resolves a JSON
    model: arrayCars[i]
  }));
}

Promise.all(promises).then(function(output) {
  for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {

    var preownedMiles = output[i].preownedMiles;
    var zipRadius = output[i].zipcodeRadius;

    if ('discount' in output[i]) {

      featuredCars.models.push({
        "name": output[i].modelName,
        "type": output[i].bodyType,
        "value": output[i].salePrice,
        "photos": []
      });

    }

    if (preownedMiles > 10000) {

      featuredCars.models.push({
        "name": output[i].modelName,
        "type": output[i].bodyType,
        "value": output[i].salePrice - 3000,
        "photos": []
      });

      featuredCars.models.photos[featuredCars.models.photos.length - 1].push(downloadImg({ // function downloadImg returns a promise which resolves the downloaded path
          urls: output[i].picURLS,
          saveThumbnail: false
        }));
    }

    if (zipRadius < 6) {

      featuredCars.models.push({
        "name": output[i].modelName,
        "type": output[i].bodyType,
        "value": output[i].salePrice - 1000,
        "photos": []
      });
      featuredCars.models.photos[featuredCars.models.photos.length - 1].push(downloadImg({ // function downloadImg returns a promise which resolves the downloaded path
          urls: output[i].picURLS,
          saveThumbnail: false
      }));
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see after the loop executes the "promises" array shall be containing an bunch promise objects. Which I resolve in the next block with Promise.all().then(). If you see, based on some condition the "photos" keys of the "featuredCars.models" object is again set to a Promise object (as the function "downloadImg" returns a Promise object). I can't change the behavior of any of these functions as they are part of a library I'm using and I have no control of modifying them.

So I'm looking for a way to iterate the "featuredCars.models" object and 
replace the value of the "photos" array with the fulfilled value of their respective Promise objects.

So far I have been trying to do it with a for loop and I observe that if I do a Promise.all() of the "featuredCars.models.photos", I don't have access to the loops counter so that I can replace the value of "featuredCars.models.photos" with the resolution of its Promise inside the ".then()".

I think I somehow need to pass the loops counter into .then(), so that I know which index of the object needs to be replaced, as not every "photos" array contains a Promise object.

I have tried my best to be as clear as possible. Please bear with me, if I sound ambiguous.

Comment: Do you really want to push the same car three times if it satisfies all three conditions?

Comment: `featuredCars.models` looks like an array in your code. It should not have a `.photos` property, should it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a loop counter variable after an asynchronous action returns, you should either use a block-scoped variable (`let` or `const`) or make a new closure.

See the problem here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(i) }, 0)
}
```

Rather than logging "0", "1", ..., "9", it logs "10" 10 times because the loop has already terminated once the callbacks fire.

With `let` in ES6:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(i) }, 0)
}
```

With a closure:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function(iInLoop) {
        setTimeout(function() {
             console.log(iInLoop)
        }, 0)
    })(i)
}
```

If you do either or these, you can add a `then()` to the photo promise that will update the value in the array based on the value of `i` in that loop cycle.